Why am I getting a 404 Page Not Found error in my Next.js 14 application?
I am encountering a 404 error, along with the correct content, in my Next.js 14 application. I have checked the folder structure, but I still don't understand what the problem is. If I route to other pages, they work fine and do not show any errors. The problem occurs only when loading the home page.
enter image description here
This is the folder structure of my app:
Folder Structure
I've checked my code and everything seems to be in order, yet the 404 error persists. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Is it always resolving 404? Or only the first time you call?
